# Level columns - recalculate when screen changes width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using some JS to make some divs the same height on a website I am working on. Flex won't work for this particular project.

The code I am using is:

```
(function() {
    function equalHeights(selector) {
        var maxHeight = 0;
        function calcEqualHeight() {
            var el = $(this);
            maxHeight = el.height() > maxHeight ? el.height() : maxHeight;
        }
        selector.each(calcEqualHeight).height(maxHeight);
    }

    equalHeights($('.level'));
})();
```

When you re-size the screen, the calculations are off unless you refresh. I am wondering if there's anyway for this to reload when the browser size is changed.

Ideally it would be good for the heights to recalculate, rather than the user having to refresh the page for it to display properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a handler for the window [`resize` event](https://api.jquery.com/resize/).

**Note:** since the resize event is called multiple times when the size changes, it's advisable to [debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) the event handler. I've used the `debounce` method from the article in the example.

```
(function() {
    function equalHeights(selector) {
        var maxHeight = 0;
        function calcEqualHeight() {
            var el = $(this);
            maxHeight = el.height() > maxHeight ? el.height() : maxHeight;
        }
        selector.each(calcEqualHeight).height(maxHeight);
    }

    var $levels = $('.level');

    equalHeights($levels);

     // 10ms after window stops resizing, the equalHeights will be called
    $(window).resize(debounce(function() {
      equalHeights($levels);
    }), 10);
})();
```